# Generating age of person

Tags: c

Can anyone tell me why this is not working?

```
{

    int age;
    int birthYear;
    char name;

    printf("Type in your birth year: \n");
    scanf("%d", birthYear);

    age = 2016 - birthYear;

    printf("You are %d years old.\n", age);
}
```

Comment: You should read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Use the `{}` button to format source code. Also, your string should be `"You are roughly %d years old.\n"` ;)

Comment: You are missing the function header, necessary library headers and some other stuff. Simple read [ask].

Comment: Do you get any compiler warnings from your code?

Comment: No, I just forgot to put & before birthYear, fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the address of your `int` to `scanf()`:

```
scanf("%d", &birthYear);
```

***Additional explanation:*** If you don't put the `&` you will pass an unitialized int to `scanf()`, and `scanf()` will interpret this as a pointer.  The input would then not be stored in the variable (which remains unititalised).  Worse: this might end-up in memory corruption.